# Need to know if the given du value for this integral/ln solution is correct

Tags: integration, logarithms

$\int \frac{2}{x(\ln x+5)^7} dx$ for that problem the example gives $u=\ln x+5$ and $du=\frac{1}{x}dx$. based on a couple other problems I thought du should be $\frac{1}{x+5}dx$ The derivative of inside ln, over what's in ln left alone. Is there something I'm missing about this? Or, since it's happened quite a few times, is this written incorrectly?

Comment: note: as you have posted, it says $\ln x+5$ and not $\ln(x+5)$

Comment: The derivative of $\ln (x)+5$ is $\frac{1}{x}$. So you end up with $\int \frac{2}{u^7}\,du$. So we are finding $\int 2u^{-7}\,du$. By the usual formula this is $\frac{2}{-6}u^{-6}+C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that inside the parenthesis you have

$$\begin{align*}
u &= \ln x + 5\\
&=\ln(x) +5\\
\end{align*}
$$

So $$du = \frac 1x \ dx$$

They omitted the parenthesis for the log. Note that $\ln(x+5)$ would never be written as $\ln x + 5$.

Comment: Ohhh. Ok. I just read it wrong. Thanks.